# What action can I take if I see a comment contains "ASAP" or some variant thereof?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, comment-flags

I saw the below kind of comments sometimes.

> Reply me immediately
>
> Please reply as soon as possible
>
> Im struck with this long time, please answer fast.

Can I flag these kind of comments? If so, can I flag as `too chatty` or something else?

Sample comment for your reference:

> [image: ASAP]

Comment: Oh, I down and close vote those immediate.    Unfortunately, there is no 'Question is annoying' close-reason.

Comment: @MartinJames So you down and close vote a post even if it fits the rules of SO and is high quality?

Comment: Comments cannot be downvoted. Such noise can be edited out of questions. Comments cannot be closed, but they can be removed.

Comment: @DavidG I cannot ever remember seeing an arrogant 'URGENT' question that  fits the rules of SO and is high quality.   They are mostly homework dumps of code, copied from other students or from websites, and they expect all their debugging done for them before the submission deadline.

Comment: Now I have to wait for one to turn up to provide an example..

Comment: ..but, if anyone sees the pseudo-mythical 'URGENT' comment on a question that fits the rules of SO and is high quality, please link it, especially if I have also commented and likely downvoted.  I would be happy with being proved wrong, incorrect, whatever..

Comment: OK, here's my first example from the reject pile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975019/i-need-complexity-of-the-codes-written-below

Comment: @MartinJames I probably agree, but I'm just saying that I don't associate comments with the quality of the question/answer. Those posts should stand on their own merit and get downvoted/closed/deleted based on their content, **not** on any subsequent comments made.

Comment: My take on these comments is that they're posted by: 1) someone sitting in an exam who's desperate for an answer RIGHT NOW! 2) people who should *really* be studying management because they believe they have a right to an answer RIGHT NOW!, or 3) someone on a submarine which is sinking rapidly towards crush depth who really, *seriously* needs an answer RIGHT NOW! In all three cases the question can be safely ignored. If (1) - do your own work. If (2) - when you sign my paycheck I'll hurry up - until then CHILL! If (3), the chances of saving them is vanishingly small - so don't worry about it.

Comment: Yet again, [this](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/55411) wonderful open letter over at Programmer's Meta applies.

Comment: If I see ASAP in questions (not in comments) I usually edit it out.

Comment: lol, when pushed: 'My client is gone and i have now suffer a lose thanks to these so called SO geniuses' - slaver.  SInce the question was obviously homework, this user was taking money for homework answers and posting the homework on SO.   This kind of activity results in ALL homework-level questions being automatically suspect.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Flag it for removal.

Those sorts of comments are *nothing* but noise.  Their timeline is not our own, and it is unlikely to inspire a quicker answer.

It's not a constructive comment, so flagging it as "not constructive" *might* be better than "too chatty", which I've more or less reserved for comments that contain remarks that are discussing something other than the question.

Comment: @pnuts I disagree. The old adage *A lack of planning on your part does not necessitate an emergency on my part* applies perfectly here. Of course, everyone wants their question answered quickly. However, if you're in a real bind and absolutely need an answer *right now*, Stack Overflow is not the resource you should be using. We are not paid on-call technicians waiting to address your every need, we are volunteers who sometimes may actually have to attend to other work, or even *gasp* leave the computer for some reason. If you need help that fast, get a support contract.

Comment: @pnuts:  I disagree.  It's *still* noise.  The onus is on the person asking for clarification to take some initiative when it's provided - even when they're not notified.  If the person makes use of the notifications system, then that'd be the best way to get someone's attention and/or ask them to review the question, which is a system that already exists and works.  I've been burned a lot by people that don't want to come back to fix glaring issues in their content, and no amount of "ASAP" comment is going to remind me to do so.

Comment: @pnuts:  The only urgency I could say that a comment like that would need is just *remove it when you see it*, analogous to how spam comments or offensive comments are dealt with.  They don't do anything but clutter up the question, so their removal would go a long way to potentially bringing the question back on-topic.